# Simplest way to use CSS transitions with fit-content for width?

Tags: html, css, codepen

I want to find out the easiest way to use `transition: 0.5s` with another style attribute of `width: fit-content`. I have a padding style attribute of `7vw`, and the transition only applies to that. It only transitions the padding that is applied to the element. How can I get it to transition the whole element? Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AustinCharb07/pen/dyJaxOm)
to this situation.

I just want something as simple as possible please!

```js
window.onload = function() {

    function openMenu() {
        document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.width = "50vw";
    }

    function closeMenu() {
        document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.width = "0";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.sideMenu {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sideMenu a {
  padding: 8px 8px 16px 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sideMenu button {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: inherit;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sideMenu a:hover button:hover {
  color: #b8b8b8;
}

.sideMenu .closebtn {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openSideMenuIcon {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #b8b8b8;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sideMenu {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sideMenu a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Summer Vacation Countdown!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A summer vacation countdown made by Austin Charbonneau, a freshman." />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <script>
        function openMenu() {
                document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.width = "fit-content";
            document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.paddingRight = "7vw";
        }

        function closeMenu() {
            document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.paddingRight = "0px";
        }
    </script>
    <div id="sideMenuID" class="sideMenu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeMenu()">&times;</a>
        <a><button onclick="openTimeSetMenu()" id="setTimeMenuOpenButton">Set Closing Time</button></a>
        <a><button onclick="" id="contactSuggestions">Contact/Suggestions</button></a>
    </div>
    <span style="position: absolute;font-size:50px;cursor:pointer;color: #b8b8b8;z-index: 0;" onclick="openMenu()">&#9776;</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to animate the width of #sideMenuID as well. Here is a working example:

```js
window.onload = function() {

    function openMenu() {
        document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.width = "50vw";
    }

    function closeMenu() {
        document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.width = "1px";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

.sideMenu {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sideMenu a {
  padding: 8px 8px 16px 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#sideMenuID {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.sideMenu button {
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: inherit;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sideMenu a:hover button:hover {
  color: #b8b8b8;
}

.sideMenu .closebtn {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openSideMenuIcon {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #b8b8b8;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sideMenu {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sideMenu a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Summer Vacation Countdown!</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A summer vacation countdown made by Austin Charbonneau, a freshman." />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <script>
        function openMenu() {
                document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.width = "400px";
            document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.paddingRight = "7vw";
        }

        function closeMenu() {
            document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.width = "0px";
            document.getElementById("sideMenuID").style.paddingRight = "0px";
        }
    </script>
    <div id="sideMenuID" class="sideMenu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeMenu()">&times;</a>
        <a><button onclick="openTimeSetMenu()" id="setTimeMenuOpenButton">Set Closing Time</button></a>
        <a><button onclick="" id="contactSuggestions">Contact/Suggestions</button></a>
    </div>
    <span style="position: absolute;font-size:50px;cursor:pointer;color: #b8b8b8;z-index: 0;" onclick="openMenu()">&#9776;</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works with ```vw``` and ```vh``` and percent values, but i want it to work with ```fit-content```...

Comment: If you would like fit-content; set the width always to fit-content and add no animation to width.
Add an animation to transform and add the following on the "hidden state": transform: translateX(-100%);
and the following on the visible state: transform: translateX(0);
You can additionals add opacity 1|0 for a more smoth fading animation.

Comment: Maybe a code example? I'm kinda new to this... :)

Comment: Yes sure! This is  a very basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/xne9uLjr/